# The DCOM configuration for 'Run application in this computer' is automatically flagged

Tags: windows, office-interop, dcom

We have an application deployed(a web app in a tomcat server) that uses the interop libraries with the following configuration.

[image]

The DCOM is configured as shown in the image."
The problem arises when the option 'Run application in this computer' seems to get flagged automatically but we don't have a clue about what is happening.

In order to delimit the exact moment when it happens: is it possible to check for this option each x seconds for example looking in the windows registry? (using for example a small console app to tracing)